# d:DataContext=d:DesignInstance does not work, not even vanilla UWP projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I am on Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4 and I would really love to see sample data during design time but 
`d:DataContext` seems to fail with visual studio.
The project is plain simple and only uses this code

```
<Page
    x:Class="DesignTime.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:DesignTime"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Class1,
                                     IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:Class1 />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" />
</Page>
```

The data context is trivial

```
public class Class1
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> Objects { get; set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        Objects = new ObservableCollection<string>(new []{"AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC"});
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour is: After I build the project in visual studio (targeting x86), the designer should display the dummy data, but it does not,. the list view remains empty until I run the application.

Instead IntelliSense complains with weird errors and very little information is available for those

[image: intellisense]

I am aware that the sample xaml above uses a separate DataContext but I am specifically looking at how to set a design time data context which would be a different class providing more dummy data so I can properly design without running the application.

Comment: I created a blank project and used your code. When I built the project, the designer can display the dummy data and didn't throw the errors. What is your system version and the target version number?

Comment: On our company machines we are bound to release 1709 where this issue occurs. I tested it at home targeting the same build 16299 but with a windows release 1903 and the issue does not appear. How is this an operating system issue? Do you have more info to that? Unfortunately our company machines cannot be easily upgraded to a newer windows.

Comment: Since it worked well on 1903, then it should have been fixed in the new version. If it is not easy to upgrad to a new system, you need to run your project to test and can't test in the design time.